# Net.Http.StringContent date format

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I'm trying to upload a file with some metadata to a Web API. Everything is fine within the developer environment. But when the same API is hosted in Azure I get the following date parsing error:

> Conversion from string "31/03/2019 11:33:52" to type 'Date' is not valid.

I guess StringContent should write the date on ISO 8601 format and it does not.

Next is a simplification of my procedure:

```
Public Async Function UploadDocFile(oHttpClient as HttpClient, url as string, ByVal oByteArray as Byte(), exs As List(Of Exception)) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim retval As Boolean
    Dim formContent = New Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent From {
        {New Net.Http.StringContent("DateCreated"), now},
        {New Net.Http.StreamContent(New IO.MemoryStream(oDocfile.Stream)), "pdf", "pdf.jpg"}
    }

    Dim response = Await oHttpClient.PostAsync(url, formContent)
    If response.StatusCode = 200 Then
        retval = True
    Else
        exs.Add(New Exception(response.ReasonPhrase))
    End If
    Return retval
End Function
```

Comment: The parameter passed to the `StringContent` constructor should be _the value_, not _the name_. It should be `{New Net.Http.StringContent(Now.ToString("SomeFormat"), "DateCreated"}` where `SomeFormat` is the format expected by the host.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Indeed, the constructor was right, but I should have specified the Sortable ("s") Format Specifier. Next code works Ok: {New Net.Http.StringContent("DateCreated"), now.toString("s")}

Comment: Check my answer below. It has additional explanation and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [Collection Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/collection-initializers/) to add items to the `MultipartFormDataContent`; you're expected to follow [this overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_MultipartFormDataContent_Add_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_System_String_) of the `Add` method, which accepts two parameters of type `HttpContent` and `String`, respectively.

Thus, the second value enclosed in the braces (`{}`) should be the *name* of the data content, not its *value*. On the other hand, the parameter passed to the [`StringContent` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_) should be the *value* (content), not the *name*. You basically have them swapped out. If you'd had `Option Strict` set to `On` *(which is something [you should do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29985039/4934172), BTW)*, you would've gotten a compiler error and would've easily identified the mistake.

Your code should look something like this:

```
Dim formContent = New Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent From
{
    {New Net.Http.StringContent(Now.ToString("SomeFormat")), "DateCreated"},
    ' More values.
}
```

..where `SomeFormat` is a format supported by the web API that you're using.